# Apache Spark in Azure Synapse 'overwrite' method Function not working

Tags: apache-spark, azure-databricks, azure-synapse

I have a nice function let allows me to overwrite and rename a file when I save the results of query to ADLS, see following

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('ops').getOrCreate()

def rename_file(origin_path, dest_path, file_type, new_name):
  filelist = mssparkutils.fs.ls(origin_path)#list all files from origin path
  filtered_filelist = [x.name for x in filelist if x.name.endswith("."+file_type)]#keep names of the files that match the type requested
  if len(filtered_filelist) > 1:#check if we have more than 1 files of that type
    print("Too many "+file_type+" files. You will need a different implementation")
  elif len(filtered_filelist) == 0: #check if there are no files of that type
    print("No "+file_type+" files found")
  else:
    mssparkutils.fs.mv(origin_path+"/"+filtered_filelist[0], dest_path+"/"+new_name+"."+file_type)#move the file to a new path (can be the same) changing the name in the process
```

I usually use this function with Databricks in which I would dbutils instead of mssparkutils.

Anyhow as an example I would the above function with the following code:

```
df_staging_ccd_probate = df_staging_ccd_probate = "abfss://root@adlspretbiukadlsdev.dfs.core.windows.net/RAW/LANDING/"

myquery.coalesce(1).write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").save(df_staging_ccd_probate+"/tempDelta")
rename_file(df_staging_ccd_probate+"/tempDelta",df_staging_ccd_probate,"parquet","filename")
mssparkutils.fs.rm(df_staging_ccd_probate+"/tempDelta",True)
```

With Databricks this would work fine, but with Apache Spark with Azure Synapse I get the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:mssparkutils.fs.mv.
: org.apache.hadoop.fs.PathExistsException: `abfss://root@adlspretbiukadlsdev.dfs.core.windows.net/RAW/LANDING/filename.parquet': File exists
```

For some reason the 'overwrite' method doesn't seem to work with Apache Spark in Synapse.

Can someone let me know what the equivalent method is to 'overwrite'? Or am I missing something?
Thanks

Just so you know

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('ops').getOrCreate()

def rename_file(origin_path, dest_path, file_type, new_name):
  filelist = dbutils.fs.ls(origin_path)#list all files from origin path
  filtered_filelist = [x.name for x in filelist if x.name.endswith("."+file_type)]#keep names of the files that match the type requested
  if len(filtered_filelist) > 1:#check if we have more than 1 files of that type
    print("Too many "+file_type+" files. You will need a different implementation")
  elif len(filtered_filelist) == 0: #check if there are no files of that type
    print("No "+file_type+" files found")
  else:
    dbutils.fs.mv(origin_path+"/"+filtered_filelist[0], dest_path+"/"+new_name+"."+file_type)#move the file to a new path (can be the same) changing the name in the process
```

with the following overwrites everytime with Databricks, so it must be something with Synapse that it doesn't work:

```
myquery.coalesce(1).write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").save(df_staging_ccd_probate+"/tempDelta")
rename_file(df_staging_ccd_probate+"/tempDelta",df_staging_ccd_probate,"parquet","filemane")
dbutils.fs.rm(df_staging_ccd_probate+"/tempDelta",True)
```

Comment: I have been troubleshooting this issue all night. I have come to the conclusion that the issue is with mssparkutils.fs.mv. But I really don't know how to fix this

Comment: Actually, I think I maybe wrong about the issue being with mssparkutils.fs.mv. I thinkg the problem stems from Synapse not being able to overwrite the file. Again, I could be wrong.

Comment: Please let me know if you would need the full stacktrace to help me resolve this, and I will put it up on github

Comment: So, after doing a bit more troubleshooting it turns out that the code:
```mssparkutils.fs.mv(origin_path+"/"+filtered_filelist[0], dest_path+"/"+new_name+"."+file_type)```

should follow the format:

```mssparkutils.mv(src, dest, create_path, overwrite)```

So, when I change the above to
```mssparkutils.fs.mv(origin_path+"/"+filtered_filelist[0], dest_path+"/"+new_name+"."+file_type, "overwrite", True)```

I now get the error
```py4j.Py4JException: Method mv([class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, class java.lang.Boolean]) does not exist```
Thoughts

Comment: Actually, I think the code works better without the quotes. 
Without the quotes I get the same error as originally shown above, which is:
```Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:mssparkutils.fs.mv.
: org.apache.hadoop.fs.PathExistsException: `abfss://root@adlspretbiukadlsdev.dfs.core.windows.net/RAW/LANDING/filename.parquet': File exists```
Any ideas welcomed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close. This is how to move the file and allow overwriting.

```
mssparkutils.fs.mv(source_path, dest_path, overwrite=True)
```

Comment: Adrian, this is major for me. Thanks

Comment: can we rename while moving like adding current date to file name?